# How can I prove that $f$ is a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Given $\gamma \geq 0$ if

$\liminf_{r\rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\frac{M(f;r)}{r^{\gamma}} = 0$

where $M(f;r) = max \{|f(z)|: |z|=r \}$. Then $f$ is polynom such that his degree are at least $\gamma$.

I can see that $f$ growth is not exponencial so he must be a polynomial, but how can I show that its degree is at least $\gamma$?

Comment: I think you mean "at most $\gamma$"... by the way, I don't think it's immediately clear that $f$ is polynomial just because it has subexponential growth. It is certainly not true in real analysis, as $f(x)=\sin(x)$ shows! Anyways, [Cauchy estimates](https://soffer801.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/cauchy-estimates/) will do the trick.

Comment: Note: in English, we call them "polynomials", not "polynoms".

Comment: sorry, but i can't see how to implement the theorem in this exercise...

Comment: I have just noticed, do you assume $f$ is analytic? If not, then the statement is false. If you do, then by using Cauchy estimates and letting $r\rightarrow\infty$ shows that $n$th coefficient in power series expansion with $n\geq\gamma$ are zero.